# Countable sum of simple functions

Tags: probability-theory

When is an infinite countable sum of simple functions a simple function?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What kind of criterion are you looking for? Depending on the definition of 'simple function' (which varies a bit) a trivial answer would likely be something like "if the sum takes on only finitely many finite values", but I guess this is not what you want....

Comment: There's no "simple" characterization other than just by definition "if and only if it takes only finitely many values". One might say that "typically" a countable sum of simple functions is not simple...

Comment: @Thomas ups, you're right.